# Calculate height of Text widget at build

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to add padding under a `SliverFixedExtentList` to fill the screen by using a `SliverPadding` and add a `Text.rich` widget at the bottom of the screen. Calculating the height of the list was rather easy because I'm setting the extent. But I should also keep the height of the `Text.rich` widget in mind.

I'm uncertain about how to calculate the height of the `Text.rich` widget at build time, is this possible? If not, what would be a better approach?

I've been using the following code:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double maxNonScrollableListSize = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - listPadding.bottom - listPadding.top - bottomFooterPadding.bottom - fontSize - 2);
    double totalChildHeight = childCount * itemExtent;
    double footerPadding = maxNonScrollableListSize > totalChildHeight ? maxNonScrollableListSize - totalChildHeight : 5.0;
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Container(
        color: new Color.fromRGBO(50, 120, 176, 1.0),
        child: new CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            new SliverPadding(
              padding: listPadding,
              sliver: new SliverFixedExtentList(
                itemExtent: itemExtent,
                delegate: new SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                  (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return new Card(
                      child: new Container(
                        child: new Center(child: new Text("Card $index")),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  childCount: childCount,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            new SliverPadding(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: footerPadding),
            ),
            new SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: new Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Container(child: new Text("ok", style: new TextStyle(fontSize: fontSize),))
                ],
              ),
            ),
            new SliverPadding(
              padding: bottomFooterPadding,
            ),
          ],
        )
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It's not possible.

The whole point of the widget system is to make widgets autonomous. Under no circumstances should they know at build time the size of their children. The only exception is when that size is predefined (such as with `PreferredSizeWidget`).

If you are **certain** you need it. Then what you want to create is not a widget, but a `RenderBox`. Which is one of the lower layers of flutter.

Comment: Is there then a better way to solve my problem which does not include calculating heights? I'd just like a Listview with a footer, if the listview does not take up all of the screen (i.e. it has 3 items) it has the footer all the way at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Consider creating another question with details about what you're trying to achieve. As this is a different problem.

Comment: Alright I did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49620212/listview-with-scrolling-footer-at-the-bottom