# Listview with scrolling Footer at the bottom

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to create a scrolling list widgets which takes displays a few items and has the ability to add a footer at the bottom which scrolls along.

If the scrolling list doesn't take up the complete height, e.g. there are only 2 items, the footer should still appear at the bottom of the screen. Here are some sketches of what I'm trying to achieve

[image: non page filling listview]
[image: page filling listview]

I tried calculating the vertical size that the listview needs but that'd mean that I need the know the height of the children at build time. Is there a better way?

**EDIT**
I'm trying to achieve the exact same thing as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283686/listview-footer-at-the-bottom-of-screen) but with Flutter of course.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You will need to create a custom RenderBox for this. As there's no widgets which supports this out of the box.

`SliverFillRemaining` comes pretty close. But it's sizing/scrolling behavior is different then what you'd expect. As, if present, will almost always make the `Scrollable`... scrollable.

Instead, we can copy paste the sources of `SliverFillRemaining`. And make some edits

```dart
class SliverFooter extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  /// Creates a sliver that fills the remaining space in the viewport.
  const SliverFooter({super.child});

  @override
  RenderSliverFooter createRenderObject(BuildContext context) =>
      RenderSliverFooter();
}

class RenderSliverFooter extends RenderSliverSingleBoxAdapter {
  @override
  void performLayout() {
    final extent =
        constraints.remainingPaintExtent - math.min(constraints.overlap, 0.0);
    double childGrowthSize = .0; // added
    if (child != null) {
      // changed maxExtent from 'extent' to double.infinity
      child!.layout(
        constraints.asBoxConstraints(minExtent: extent),
        parentUsesSize: true,
      );
      childGrowthSize = constraints.axis == Axis.vertical
          ? child!.size.height
          : child!.size.width; // added
    }
    final paintedChildSize =
        calculatePaintOffset(constraints, from: 0.0, to: extent);
    assert(
        paintedChildSize.isFinite,
        'The calculated paintedChildSize '
        '$paintedChildSize for child $child is not finite.');
    assert(
        paintedChildSize >= 0.0,
        'The calculated paintedChildSize was '
        '$paintedChildSize but is not greater than or equal to zero. '
        'This can happen if the child is too big in which case it '
        'should be sized down or if the SliverConstraints.scrollOffset '
        'was not correct.');
    geometry = SliverGeometry(
      // used to be this : scrollExtent: constraints.viewportMainAxisExtent,
      scrollExtent: math.max(extent, childGrowthSize),
      paintExtent: paintedChildSize,
      maxPaintExtent: paintedChildSize,
      hasVisualOverflow: extent > constraints.remainingPaintExtent ||
          constraints.scrollOffset > 0.0,
    );
    if (child != null) {
      setChildParentData(child!, constraints, geometry!);
    }
  }
}
```

---

Here I changed one 3 things

- Unconstrained the child `maxExtent`. Because if there's no more screen-space available, that would enforce a height of 0 to the footer.
- changed `SliverGeometry` `scrollExtent` from "full screen height" to "actual available size". So that it actually only *fill* the remaining visible space. Not fill the screen.
- added a minimum value to that same `scrollExtent`, equal to the actual footer height. So that if there's no more space remaining in the viewport, the children is simply added without any spacing around it.

We can now use it inside our `CustomScrollView` as usual.

End result :

```dart
    CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverFixedExtentList(
          itemExtent: 42.0,
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
            return SizedBox.expand(
              child: Card(),
            );
          }, childCount: 42),
        ),
        SliverFooter(
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Container(
              height: 42.0,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Comment: You should consider making a pull request for this. This should be a part of the Flutter repository imo.

Comment: Agreed. I'll do it.

Comment: @RémiRousselet Thanks for the code, works well. When there is a input field in one of the sliverlist, after minimizing the keyboard, the footer snaps back to the bottom but the remaining list all end up at the top with lot of space between the last list item and the footer, is there anyway to lower the list also.

Comment: how to achieve a real footer that stays there, even if there are many items above?

Comment: @RémiRousselet Have you created the PR yet? how did it turn out?

Comment: There is no enough upvotes for your answer... Thank you so much...

Comment: @RémiRousselet as I see now, they didn't accept your PR :) (or you didn't created it unfortunately) 

Thank you for the great solution!

Answer (score 9):

This can be achieved by using a `SingleChildScrollView` with special constraints, as explained [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html).

Take a look at the example below:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
      return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: constraints.copyWith(
            minHeight: constraints.maxHeight,
            maxHeight: double.infinity,
          ),
          child: IntrinsicHeight(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(height: 200, color: Colors.blue),
                Container(height: 200, color: Colors.orange),
                Container(height: 200, color: Colors.green),
                Container(height: 50, color: Colors.pink),
                Expanded(
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      color: Colors.red,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                      child: Text('FOOTER', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

This builds the following layout:

[image: layout]

If you change the height of the pink container to something larger, say 500, you will see the footer also scrolls with the entire list.

Thanks to [Simon Lightfoot](https://github.com/slightfoot) for his help pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Way simpler than the accepted answer, and works!

Answer (score 4):

To add Footer in ListView with Builder

1. Just add `+1` in `itemCount` for example: `itemCount:list.length + 1`
2. And while returning `customWidget` check the condition `list.length == index` just return a `SizedBox(height:"required height of footer ")`.

Code:

```
ListView.builder(
itemCount: list.length+1,
physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        if (list.length == index) {
          return;
        }
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => PlotDetail(list[index])));
      },
      child: list.length != index?PlotListItemWidget(list[index]):SizedBox(height: 100,));
   },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I've created [flat_list](https://pub.dev/packages/flat_list) widget which has similar specifications as in React Native's FlatList. Below will simply work.

```
FlatList(
+  listFooterWidget: const Footer(),
  data: items.value,
  buildItem: (item, index) {
    var person = items.value[index];

    return ListItemView(person: person);
  },
),
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use stack to build a sticky footer inside a scrollable widget like this:

```
Scaffold(
      body:Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, 
        children: [
          ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 1,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Container( // Scrollable contents here
                color: Colors.red,
                height: 3000,
                width: 1000,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container( // Footer
            height:50,
            color:Colors.blue[900],
            width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child:Center(child:Text("Footer")),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

All the scrollable contents will be inside Listview.builder and the content of the footer will be outside of it.