# Creating a listview with listview in footer

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to add a ListView using a custom `SliverFooter` as defined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49620212/listview-with-scrolling-footer-at-the-bottom) which creates a `RenderSliverFooter` to create a Footer in a `ListView` that is always at the bottom of the screen like this design at https://i.stack.imgur.com/hE8Tn.png.

```
class SliverFooter extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  /// Creates a sliver that fills the remaining space in the viewport.
  const SliverFooter({
    Key key,
    Widget child,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  RenderSliverFooter createRenderObject(BuildContext context) => new RenderSliverFooter();
}

class RenderSliverFooter extends RenderSliverSingleBoxAdapter {
  /// Creates a [RenderSliver] that wraps a [RenderBox] which is sized to fit
  /// the remaining space in the viewport.
  RenderSliverFooter({
    RenderBox child,
  }) : super(child: child);

  @override
  void performLayout() {
    final extent = constraints.remainingPaintExtent - math.min(constraints.overlap, 0.0);
    var childGrowthSize = .0; // added
    if (child != null) {
       // changed maxExtent from 'extent' to double.infinity
      child.layout(constraints.asBoxConstraints(minExtent: extent, maxExtent: double.infinity), parentUsesSize: true);
      childGrowthSize = constraints.axis == Axis.vertical ? child.size.height : child.size.width; // added
    }
    final paintedChildSize = calculatePaintOffset(constraints, from: 0.0, to: extent);
    assert(paintedChildSize.isFinite);
    assert(paintedChildSize >= 0.0);
    geometry = new SliverGeometry(
      // used to be this : scrollExtent: constraints.viewportMainAxisExtent,
      scrollExtent: math.max(extent, childGrowthSize),
      paintExtent: paintedChildSize,
      maxPaintExtent: paintedChildSize,
      hasVisualOverflow: extent > constraints.remainingPaintExtent || constraints.scrollOffset > 0.0,
    );
    if (child != null) {
      setChildParentData(child, constraints, geometry);
    }
  }
}
```

As stated in the answer you can use the `SliverFooter` like this:

```
new CustomScrollView(
  slivers: <Widget>[
    new SliverFixedExtentList(
      itemExtent: 42.0,
      delegate: new SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
        return new SizedBox.expand(
          child: new Card(),
        );
      }, childCount: 42),
    ),
    new SliverFooter(
      child: new Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: new Container(
          height: 42.0,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

The issue is when trying to add a `ListView` to the `SliverFooter` there is this error: `A RenderSliverFooter expected a child of type RenderBox but received a child of type RenderSliverList`.

Is there another way to create a `SliverFooter` so I can display another ListView in the footer? The current way only can display a fixed height it seems.

Comment: Did you try wrapping your listview inside a container ?

Comment: @Rémi Rousselet Yes, I tried that, it leads to the same error message if you try adding another `SliverFixedExtentList` to the `Container` of `SliverFooter`