# How to create a scroll view with fixed footer with Flutter?

Tags: layout, dart, flutter

I would like to create a view that has to have a `Column` with a scroll view (e.g. something like `SingleChildScrollView`) and a footer regardless of the screen size. If the screen is big enough, it will use the empty space between the scroll and the footer, if not, it will expand and only make the widget above the footer scrollable.

It's more or less like [Listview with scrolling Footer at the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49620212/listview-with-scrolling-footer-at-the-bottom) but with a diference that I want the keyboard to overflow the footer and it also should stay in place.

Something like

[image: example]

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 30.0, top: 80.0),
              child: Form(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                   // Multiple widgets and form fields
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
            child: SafeArea(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  // Footer widgets
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Can you include a small draft of the desired layout?

Comment: @RémiRousselet done.

Comment: I was more thinking of a screenshot/drawing instead. Something visual

Comment: @RémiRousselet added.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Even though the Rémi answer being right, I've actually found an easier way to achieve what I was looking for by just combining the `LayoutBuilder` with the `IntrinsicHeight`.

```
class ScrollableFooter extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
      return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: constraints.copyWith(
            minHeight: constraints.maxHeight,
            maxHeight: double.infinity,
          ),
          child: IntrinsicHeight(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
               // Your body widgets here
                Expanded(
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: // Your footer widget
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, in my opinion much more clean than responding to MediaQuerys.

Comment: you can also use `Spacer()` instead of Expanded

Comment: @RomanPanaget in some scenarios won't work properly because you want to assign the available space to the footer widget and align it inside that space at the bottom. With `Spacer()` you will have another "empty" widget using the space in between and the footer will actually shrink to fit at most its size.

Comment: Check it out the result is the same

Answer (score 34):

For those who were looking to implement **just footer with scrollview** in a simple way, below code might help :

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: buildAppBar('Some cool appbar'),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  PackageCard(),
                  PackageCard(),
                  PackageCard(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Text('Your super cool Footer'),
            color: Colors.amber,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Visual representation:-

```
---Column
    |
    |---Expanded--
                 |-SingleChildScrollView (column /YOUR SCROLLABLE VIEW)
    |
    |-Container(YOUR FOOTER)
```

I used `expanded` with `SinglechildScrollView` over here

Comment: Thanks. It's also works for fixed header content. Just need to swap the "YOUR FOOTER" code snippet to the top, before content.

Comment: Simple and elegant solution ... don't know why it is not accepted as answer

Comment: Great solution, thanks!

Comment: Great solution, I was looking for this

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Simple as it can be.

Answer (score 10):

The accepted solution works in many cases, but it becomes tricky when you want to use something like a ListView because it can't provide an intrinsic height. I tried to find some different solution, and turns out I could, and it seems more flexible. I managed to solve this situation using slivers. Where the content is inside a sliver, and the footer is also inside a sliver.

Tip: Watch "The Boring Flutter Development Show, Ep. 12", which is all about slivers.

```
return Scaffold(
  body: CustomScrollView(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    slivers: [
      SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            //content widgets
          ],
        ),
      ),
      SliverFillRemaining(
        hasScrollBody: false,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            //footer widgets,
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 7):

The difficulty is that `Column` and `SingleChildScrollView` have a hard time working together because one needs constraints and the other removes them.

The trick is to use a `CustomMultiChildLayout` and do the calculations yourself. Helped by `MediaQuery` to obtain the size of the keyboard, so that the footer can disappear to leave more room for the content.

Here's a reusable widget that does it for you:

```
class FooterLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  const FooterLayout({
    Key key,
    @required this.body,
    @required this.footer,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Container body;
  final Container footer;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomMultiChildLayout(
      delegate: _FooterLayoutDelegate(MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets),
      children: <Widget>[
        LayoutId(
          id: _FooterLayout.body,
          child: body,
        ),
        LayoutId(
          id: _FooterLayout.footer,
          child: footer,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

enum _FooterLayout {
  footer,
  body,
}

class _FooterLayoutDelegate extends MultiChildLayoutDelegate {
  final EdgeInsets viewInsets;

  _FooterLayoutDelegate(this.viewInsets);

  @override
  void performLayout(Size size) {
    size = Size(size.width, size.height + viewInsets.bottom);
    final footer =
        layoutChild(_FooterLayout.footer, BoxConstraints.loose(size));

    final bodyConstraints = BoxConstraints.tightFor(
      height: size.height - max(footer.height, viewInsets.bottom),
      width: size.width,
    );

    final body = layoutChild(_FooterLayout.body, bodyConstraints);

    positionChild(_FooterLayout.body, Offset.zero);
    positionChild(_FooterLayout.footer, Offset(0, body.height));
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRelayout(MultiChildLayoutDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Used as such:

```
FooterLayout(
  body: body,
  footer: footer,
),
```

Comment: There is one issue with`footer: footer`, I have included `footer: TextField(..)` and when click on input my keyboard popup over the footer area and hides the TextField area

Answer (score 6):

How I solved this was to wrap the fixed `Footer` and The `SingleChildScrollView` in a `Stack` widget then align the `Footer` accordingly.

```
class ScrollableFooter extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                // Your body widgets here
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: // Your fixed Footer here,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: IMHO still the most simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Although the accepted answer seems to work on mobile devices, problems occur when the width is (much) bigger than the height. When that happens, the `IntrinsicHeight` acts like an `AspectRatio`, and the height increases so the footer is pushed off the screen.

I think the problem is with the definition used by the [`IntrinsicHeight`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html) of its internal workings:

> ... instead size itself to a more reasonable height.

I can confirm that @Rémi's solutions works also in those cases.

It deserves to be a standard widget provided by the Flutter framework.

Answer (score 0):

To create a footer with scrollable screen we can use stack widget with ListView.builder and SingleChildScrollview as:

```
    Scaffold(
      body:Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, 
        children: [
          ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 1,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Container( // Scrollable contents here
                color: Colors.red,
                height: 3000,
                width: 1000,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container( // Footer
            height:50,
            color:Colors.blue[900],
            width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child:Center(child:Text("Footer")),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

**Tricky, but sticky.**

The only way I found in a few hours.

P.S. I need a header card, a message list, and a submit message footer, so SingleChildScrollView doesn't seem to be the best.

```
return CustomScrollView(
  controller: controller,
  slivers: [
    YourAwesomeContent(),
    SliverLayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        final minHeight = constraints.remainingPaintExtent - controller.offset;

        return SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
              minHeight: minHeight > 0 ? minHeight : 0,
            ),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [YourAwesomeFooter()],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?