# How can I align in Flutter an area at the bottom of screen only if the content above does fit in screen. If not, all content should be scrollable

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I would like to have a screen in Flutter with 2 buttons that should always stay at the bottom screen, unless the height of the content above the buttons plus the height of the 2 buttons overflows the screen height, in which case I would like that all content should be scrollable. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi Calian! Welcome! Here is the code you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/55563627/1010710

Comment: Exactly what I needed, it worked. Thanks a lot.